# -fno-omit-frame-pointer without optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, pointers, frame

I was wondering what -fno-omit-frame-pointer will do without optimization?

> CXXFLAGS = -Wall -ggdb3 -DDEBUG -fno-omit-frame-pointer

Isn't it that fomit-frame-pointer auto turned on at all levels of -O (except -O0)? I assume in my example it is -O0 by default.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: on x86 and family, `-fomit-frame-pointer` is **not** enabled by default for higher optimization levels because it could impede debugging.

Comment: Note that on architectures such as x86-64 and arm, there is no frame pointer generated by default (it's specified in the ABI), so this option will cause the compiler to produce a frame pointer register.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already imply yourself, `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is just ignored in your case, as the frame pointer wouldn't be ommitted anyways in the default -O0.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it Ox are just shortcuts for a set of optimization flags. The default optimization is zero, so using one flag without Ox, should do just that optimization.

In my opinion, omitting the frame pointer increases debugging difficulty for a modest performance gain.

Comment: *"In my opinion, omitting the frame pointer..."* - it makes stack traces nearly useless. `bt full` will be crippled.